# How to remove lines with same domain

Tags: bash, perl, sed, cmd

Have large txt file of 1 million lines. 
Example:

```
http://e-planet.ru/hosting/
http://www.anelegantchaos.org/
http://site.ru/e3-den-vtoroj/
https://escrow.webmoney.ru/about.aspx
http://e-planet.ru/feedback.html
```

How to clean it of lines with same domains?

I need clean one of `http://e-planet.ru/hosting/` or `http://e-planet.ru/feedback.html`

Comment: `sort file | uniq > file.new`

Comment: when you encounter similar domains, what output do you want ? remove both ? keep the first one? Just output the domain ?

Comment: @Jayesh how do you deal with same domain, different pages?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understand your question at first. Here is an awk 1-liner :

```
awk -F'/' '!a[$3]++' myfile
```

Test input :

```
http://e-planet.ru/hosting/
http://www.anelegantchaos.org/
http://site.ru/e3-den-vtoroj/
https://escrow.webmoney.ru/about.aspx
http://e-planet.ru/feedback.html
https://escrow.webmoney.ru/woopwoop
httpp://whatever.com/slk
```

Output :

```
http://e-planet.ru/hosting/
http://www.anelegantchaos.org/
http://site.ru/e3-den-vtoroj/
https://escrow.webmoney.ru/about.aspx
httpp://whatever.com/slk
```

Here, the second occurences of `http://e-planet.ru/` and `https://escrow.webmoney.ru/` are removed.

This script splits the lines using `/` as a separator, and compares the 3rd column (the domain) to see if there are duplicates. If it is unique, it will be printed. It is to be noted that it only works if **ALL** urls are preceeded by `whateverprotocol//`. The double slash is important because this is what makes the 3rd column the domain

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $in, '<', 'in.txt' or die $!;

my %seen;
while(<$in>){
    chomp;
    my ($domain) = /[http:|https]\/\/(.+?)\//g;
    $seen{$domain}++;
    print "$_\n" if $seen{$domain} == 1;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, lines with same domains still in out.txt

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm not able to reply to fugu post,

I think the problem might be that you have more that one URL in one line, so try this out:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $in, '<', 'in.txt' or die $!;

my %seen;
while(<$in>){
    chomp;
    for (split /\s/) {
      my ($url) = /[http:|https]\/\/(.+?)\//g;
      $seen{$url}++;
      print "$_\n" if $seen{$url} == 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this achieve that my answer doesn't? You can't just copy and paste my answer with a few minor changes! They should be added as comments below my original answer

Comment: @fugu he couldn't as his rep was too low.

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about are the domains of those URI's, then I suggest that you filter them out first.

Then it's a simple process of sorting them and specifying you only want unique entries:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if m{//(.+?)/}' file | sort | uniq > uniq_domains.txt
```